# fetch crashlytics report for more than 90 days

Tags: android, ios, crashlytics

How do I fetch crashlytics report for more than 90 days? I can select the date only for 90 days. We're trying to get at least a year data for comparision.

Answer (score 5):

Mike from Fabric here. We currently don't store data longer then 90 days within [Crashlytics](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/data-privacy.html#crashlytics). Our data retention policies are 90 days.

If you start using Firebase [Crashlytics](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/in-app-messaging-crashlytics.html), you could link data into Big Query and then store that data for long as you want.

Comment: is it documented somewhere ?

Comment: Yep, to set the integration up, it's documented here: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery and here: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

If you're just after a comparison of crash-free user percentage between two time periods, you can actually get this via `Analytics` -> `Dashboard`. The data seems very rounded, and you can't view more information, but it's better than nothing!

[image: crash free users on Firebase Analytics]

Comment: How to view this in https://analytics.google.com/ 2022 ?

Comment: @AshrafAmin in your report you should add new table, search for "stability" keyword